# Does `tree_method = 'exact'` in `xgboost` really mean exact greedy algorithm?

Tags: xgboost

Does `tree_method = 'exact'` in `xgboost` really mean using the exact greedy algorithm for split finding?

I'm asking this question because `xgboost` runs unreasonably fast. Here is the script that I used for running test

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor as rr
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pickle 
import sys
from time import time

t1 = time()
data = sys.argv[1]
with open(data, 'rb') as source:
    data = pickle.load(source)
np.random.shuffle(data)
x = [item[0] for item in data]
y = [item[1] for item in data]
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 100)
eval_set = [(x_train, y_train), (x_val, y_val)]

# Exact model
model_exact = rr(max_depth = 5, 
                 n_estimators = 1,
                 slient = False, 
                 min_child_weight = 0, 
                 tree_method = 'exact')
model_exact.fit(x_train, 
                y_train, 
                eval_set=eval_set,
                eval_metric="mae",
                early_stopping_rounds=30)
t2 = time()
print(f"Time used: {t2 - t1}")
```

The pickled data used for testing has been uploaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19Wm1d5z27yl9iqZKn8nAgjysuc1lRaCT/view?usp=sharing).

There are `96` features in each instance, and there are in total `11450` instances.

`xgboost` finds the first split in `0.9804270267486572s` by running on a single core (`1.3 GHz Intel Core i5`). If `xgboost` actually performs a greedy search of all the possible splits, it means `xgboost` evaluates `11450 x 96 = 1099200` splits in just `0.9804270267486572s`!

Is `xgboost` really such powerful? Or, do I misunderstand `tree_method = exact`?